# Can I create a drill-through button from data in Deneb?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, vega, deneb

I'm using Deneb to build some highly customised reporting in PowerBI, and it's been pretty brilliant so far.

However, in one view, I want to create a tiled map based on some data, but for each tile in that map I want to link to a drillthrough page. I can enable drillthrough on these, even using the modern experience but it's still a long hover + click.

I've tried using a hyperlink and filter in URL to take me to the drillthrough page, but while this works, it reloads the whole report, which isn't exactly fast.

Is it possible to create a drill-through button (the same as a native PowerBI navigation button) so that a single left click on these does the job quickly?

Comment: Does clicking on your custom visual, cross-highlight other visuals? If yes, then you can create the same native PBI drill-through button. The user will still need to select a tile in your visual, after that the button will be active. [Create a drillthrough button in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-drill-through-buttons).

Comment: These are good solutions - but still require two clicks. I'm trying to give a navigation like experience with a single click on the custom viz only.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use the sample workbook that comes with Deneb. On the Getting Started page, insert a blank button.

[image]

Set the action and destination.

[image]

Your button now works.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah, sorry, slightly different scenario - I want my deneb visualisation itself to include a button, eg. imagine a scatterplot, when I click a point on the plot, I want it to drill-through like a powerbi native button

Comment: Only by using a hyperlink which you have already tried.

Comment: thanks for your guidance, you are one of my teams heroes!